# How to capture/isolate a specific substring in text with repeated formatting?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, capture-group

I'm learning regular expressions and I'm not sure how to "take" something specific out of the output.

Example - I want to retrieve specific CSS style's value.

Here's an simplified example:

```
$source = 'foo { bar: Something }
           foo { bar: Else }
           foo { bar: Yay }';
```

I want to output this after var_dump:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Something"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Else"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Yay"
}
```

Here's my regex:

```
preg_match_all("/foo\s*{\s*bar:\s*[A-Za-z]*\s*}/",$source,$matches);
    
foreach($matches as $example) {
   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($example);
   echo '</pre>';
   }
```

And I'm getting:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "foo { bar: Something }"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "foo { bar: Else }"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "foo { bar: Yay }"
}
```

How to limit my output data so it will display only the desired content not everything that matches regex?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all("/foo\s*{\s*bar:\s*([A-Za-z]*)\s*}/",$source,$matches);
                                  ^----     ^----
```

Parentheses in this case are called "capturing group"

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your regular expression into

```
/foo\s*{\s*bar:\s*([A-Za-z]*)\s*}/
```

and then look at the output again. You will then probably see entries in your output with only the text you want to fetch.

By using `(` and `)` you create a group within your regular expression, and the preg_match_all function will output the content only within those groups as well.

### Output array

An example:

```
$text = 'Here comes a number: 5, here comes a number: 3
          and here comes a number: 4';
preg_match_all( '/[Hh]ere comes a number: ([0-9])/', $text, $matches );
```

After running this code, `$matches` will now be:

```
array(
    array( 'Here comes a number: 5', '5' ),
    array( 'Here comes a number: 5', '5' ),
    array( 'Here comes a number: 5', '5' )
)
```

As you can see, `$matches` will contain an array for every string that matches. The first entry (`$matches[0]`) will always contain the complete matched string. The other indices (`$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]` and so on) will only contain the value of the specified groups in order. If you specify an optional group (for example `test([0-9])?`) the associated index will contain a `null` value.

### Excluding groups from the output

Sometimes you want to specify a group but don't want to include it in the output array. For example:

```
$text = 'Here comes a number: 5, here comes another number: 3
          and here comes a number: 4';
preg_match_all( '/[Hh]ere comes a(nother)? number: ([0-9])/', $text, $matches );
```

I added a group for `nother` because I want it to be optional. Now my `$matches[1]` contains `"nother"` or `null`, and my `$matches[2]` contains the actual number. Since I'm not interested in whether the user chose to write *"another"* or *"a"*, I would like to exclude this group from the output.

This can be done by starting the group with `(?:`. The resulting code:

```
$text = 'Here comes a number: 5, here comes a number: 3
           and here comes a number: 4';
preg_match_all( '/[Hh]ere comes a(?:nother)? number: ([0-9])/', $text, $matches );
```

The group `(?:nother)` gets ignored in the output, and `$matches[1]` references to the actual number we are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses around the region you want to match.